# How to disable the HTTP Referer header in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, headers

I read several different solutions to disable the Referer header in Safari but no one worked. I also installed [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) but it didn't solve the problem.

Do you know a valid solution to disable the HTTP Referer header in Safari? Is there any configuration option?
In practice, I don't want my browser to send the real Referer header but just an empty value.

In Firefox you can use the WebDeveloper toolbar or change internal settings via about:config.

Comment: I guess you know what you're doing, but disabling it may make some sites stop serving images to your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Might consider looking into something like privoxy, which can do that, as well as quite a few other things.